# Populate Bootstrap Dropdown Button from CSV/Flask

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm trying to get my flask app to display a list of categories from my database which is stored on a csv. The column of categories exist in a CSV which I'm calling to a list, then trying to display on a bootstrap dropdown button. From Flask:

```
@app.route('/')
def test():

    data= df['categories'].tolist()
    return render_template('test.html', data= data)
```

From there, I take the variable data and inject it into the Bootstrap dropdown menu button:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <select name= "datum" method="GET" action="/">
          {% for datum in data[1:] %}
             <option value= "{{datum}}">{{datum}}</option>"
          {% endfor %}
       </select>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{data}}</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
 </div>
```

The first button is what I want, but its a button within a button.. It also disappears when I click it and nothing gets input.

[image: The button kind of works but it disappears when you select an item]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a select inside a droDown button, which i designed to display options in `<a>` tags.

Please try the code below:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            {% for datum in data[1:] %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{datanum}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

You also have a " right after the `</option>` closing tag, but it has nothing to do with the issue.